# Parsing text file containing unique pattern using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to parse a text file containing this pattern "KEYWORD: Out:" and dump the result into output file using Python?

input.txt

```
DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf0000 In:0x80000000.1110ffff.
DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf00cc In:0x80000000.1110ffaa.
```

output.txt

```
0xaaaf0000:1110ffff 
0x80000000:1110ffaa
```

Comment: Where is the "KEYWORD: Output:" pattern in your example input.txt? I don't see `Output` anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
import re 

txt='''\
DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf0000 In:0x80000000.1110ffff.
DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf00cc In:0x80000000.1110ffaa.'''

pat=r'KEYWORD: Out:(0x[a-f0-9]+)[ \t]+In:0x[a-f0-9]+\.([a-f0-9]+)'

>>> '\n'.join([m[0]+':'+m[1] for m in re.findall(pat, txt)])
0xaaaf0000:1110ffff
0xaaaf00cc:1110ffaa
```

If you want to do this line-by-line from a file:

```
import re

pat=r'KEYWORD: Out:(0x[a-f0-9]+)[ \t]+In:0x[a-f0-9]+\.([a-f0-9]+)'

with open(ur_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        m=re.search(pat, line) 
        if m:
            print(m.group(1)+':'+m.group(2))
```

Comment: Yes, you can open the file and read it in place of using `txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: lines
Out[6]:
['DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf0000 In:0x80000000.1110ffff.',
 'DEBUG 2020-11:11:17.401 KEYWORD: Out:0xaaaf00cc In:0x80000000.1110ffaa.']

In [7]: [x.split('Out:')[1].split(' ')[0] + ':' + x.split('In:')[1].split('.')[1] for x in lines]
Out[7]: ['0xaaaf0000:1110ffff', '0xaaaf00cc:1110ffaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2nd line for your 'output.txt' might be wrong (or complex if not - you'd need to point this out).

Otherwise, maybe a RegEx like this:

```
(.*Out:)(0x[0-9a-f]{1,8}) In:0x[0-9a-f]{1,8}\.([0-9a-f]{1,8}).
```

https://regex101.com/r/lMrR06/2